# Datepicker doesn't close on closing jquery modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker on jquery modal window. When I close the modal window without closing the datepicker it stays visible on my front page. I tried to focusout but it didn't help me and also tried mouseleave but to make it work I need to hover over the datepicker and move out to hide it.

```
$("#datepicker").append(label);
            fromInput.datepicker( {
                showOn: "both",
                minDate: -30,
                maxDate: 0,
                showAnim: "slide",
                buttonImage: "#",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                onSelect: function(fromDate, inst){
                  oDTSettings.minDate = fromDate;
                  toInput.datepicker("option", "minDate",  oDTSettings.minDate);                    
                }
            } );

            fromInput.datepicker("setDate", minDate);

$('.ui-datepicker').live('mouseleave', function() {
            $('.ui-datepicker').hide()});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and/or a jsFiddle showing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue where the z-index of the datepicker needs to be greater than the z-index of the dialog.

Try adding css similar to the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker
    {
        z-index: 1001 !important; /* must be > than popup editor (1000) */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I assume if the z-index of datepicker is less than that of the jquery dialog modal it wouldn't be visible on the modal window. I am thinking there might be something that I am missing

Comment: I thought the same thing... it's very odd